# Cheese will start from terminal but not main menu on 20.04

Tags: 20.04, webcam, mate, cheese

I'm running Ubuntu MATE 20.04.2. When I try to launch Cheese from the main menu, a small bar (like a minimised window) appears in the panel at the bottom of the screen, saying "Starting Cheese". After a few seconds it vanishes, and Cheese does not launch.

However, when I try to open Cheese from the MATE terminal, it works straight away!

```
$ which cheese
/usr/bin/cheese

$ which -a cheese
/usr/bin/cheese
/bin/cheese
```

I have tried changing the command in Cheese's menu entry from `cheese` to `/usr/bin/cheese` and `/bin/cheese`, both times without any luck. I also tried `mate-terminal -e "cheese"`, but again no luck. I tried setting Cheese's menu entry to "Application in terminal" as well as "Application" - no luck from either.

I don't know where logfiles for Cheese would be, and in this age of systemd I can't consult /var/log/messages anymore. I did try:

```
$ dmesg | grep "cheese"
```

but nothing showed up.

The only possible clue I have is that when I first launched Cheese from the command line and took four photos, when I closed it I saw the following in the terminal:

```
$ cheese

(cheese:16782): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:47:37.203: Source ID 6792 was not found when attempting to remove it

(cheese:16782): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:47:54.570: Source ID 8525 was not found when attempting to remove it

(cheese:16782): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:48:46.087: Source ID 9582 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

Answer (score 0):

The normal Cheese package puts its [executable](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=cheese) into `/usr/bin/cheese` and not to `/bin/cheese`.

So you have to remove the latter by

```
sudo rm /bin/cheese
```

and then reinstall the package by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall cheese
```

and then retry launching Cheese from terminal or MATE menu.